# Partition List in 2 parts

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I came up with the following code while trying to solve the [Leetcode partition list](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-list/) problem

Though my solution is accepted, I am not happy with a few of the additional variables which I am creating. In the code below, I would like to avoid creation of `tailEnd` and `headEnd` variables somehow.

Can you please review the code and suggest a better way to write this code.

```
public ListNode partition(ListNode head, int x) {
    ListNode partitionHead = null;
    ListNode partitionTail = null;
    ListNode headEnd = null;
    ListNode tailEnd = null;

    ListNode node = head;

    while (node != null) {
        if (node.val <x ) {
            if (partitionHead == null) {
                partitionHead = node;
            } else {
                headEnd.next = node;
            }
            headEnd = node;
        } else {
            if (partitionTail == null) {
                partitionTail = node;
            } else {
                tailEnd.next = node;
            }
            tailEnd = node;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }

    if (tailEnd != null) {
        tailEnd.next = null;
    }

    if (partitionHead == null) {
        return partitionTail;
    }

    headEnd.next = partitionTail;

    return partitionHead;
}
```

Comment: Looks nice;  my only thought would be the `while` could be better expressed as `for (ListNode node = head; node != null; node = node.next) {`

Comment: Can you copy-paste the problem description to the question? Leetcode isn't responding to me (and to make sure the eventual downfall of the site will not make this post useless).

Comment: leetcode often pushes you into creating solutions, that "only work" but mostly lack the quality of real software craftmanship - but i love these exercises :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### violation of the [IOSP](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Integration_Operation_Segregation_Principle_IOSP)

it would have helped me greatly to understand your code if you had applied the clean code rule of IOSP:

> IOSP calls for a clear separation:
>
> - Either a method contains exclusively logic, meaning transformations, control structures or API invocations. Then it’s called an Operation.
> - Or a method does not contain any logic but exclusively calls other methods within its code basis. Then it’s called Integration.

**what i would have expected:**

```
if(isBelowThreshold(currentNode)){
    pushToHead(currentNode );
}else{
    pushToTail(currentNode);
}
currentNode = getNext();
```

**what i actually received:**

```
if (node.val <x ) {
    if (partitionHead == null) {
        partitionHead = node;
    } else {
        headEnd.next = node;
    }
    headEnd = node;
} else {
    if (partitionTail == null) {
        partitionTail = node;
    } else {
        tailEnd.next = node;
    }
    tailEnd = node;
}
node = node.next;
```

**IOSP is super simple and super valuable**, it:

- splits your code into testable methods
- increases readability and reduces complexity
- makes your code easier to change (just add a step or remove one or change order)

if you need more inspiriation about read [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/clean-code-development-integration-operation-separation-principle-ec85a0e47bcb)

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplify conditionals for possibly `null` head using dummy variables

The algorithm of the posted code is very nice and simple, congratulations.
What makes it a bit difficult to understand is the many conditionals for the potential `null` heads.
A nice trick in situations like this is using a dummy variable that points to the head.
This lets you work with nodes that are guaranteed to not be null, for example:

```
public ListNode partition(ListNode head, int x) {
    var dummyLeft = new ListNode();
    var dummyRight = new ListNode();
    
    var left = dummyLeft;
    var right = dummyRight;
    for (var node = head; node != null; node = node.next) {
        if (node.val < x) {
            left.next = node;
            left = left.next;
        } else {
            right.next = node;
            right = right.next;
        }
    }
    
    left.next = dummyRight.next;
    right.next = null;
    return dummyLeft.next;
}
```

#### Limit variables to the minimal necessary scope

The `node` variable is only needed in the loop body.
So it's nice to use a `for` loop,
to avoid the mistake of accidentally using it outside of the loop.

#### Use better names

Since there are multiple lists involved inside the function,
the terms "head" and "tail" can be confusing.
That's why I used "left" and "right" instead in the above example code.

#### Use `var`

Modern Java supports the `var` keyword, and it helps to type less (no pun intended) where the variable type is clear enough.